# What is Difference between ClassNotFoundException vs NoClassDefFoundError vs Could not find or load main class XYZ?

Tags: java

I explored multiple sites but could not actually understand difference between them.I would like to know the exact difference between three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` - [is](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) a *run-time error* thrown when the bytecode of the class (i.e. corresponding `.class` file) cannot be found at run-time.

- Imagine you've compiled classes `A.java` and `B.java` and `A` is using `B`; however, later on, you've removed compiled `B.class` file. So, compilation went fine, but afterwards, actual bytecode of the class definition has been removed, as you removed `B.class`. Now, if you run your `A` (which uses `B`), you will end up having `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

`ClassNotFoundException` - [is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) a *checked exception* thrown when your application tries to load the class through its String name, but the class isn't available on classpath.

- An example can be `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");` method call in your code, when, however, you don't have `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` available on the classpath.

`Couldn't find or load main class XYZ` - is an error, indicating, that the class you instruct JVM to run, doesn't contain the *must have* entry-point `public static void main(String[] args)` method and one of these reasons can lead to that error:

- you don't provide a correct Fully Qualified Name of your main class;
- main method is not defined with the correct signature;
- you messed up the packaging / you don't run the program with `super.sub.grandchild.MainClass` name;
- you have `.class` postfix after your classname, which you should remove.

Answer (score 4):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown,if a classfile references a class, that couldn't be found at runtime, but was available at compiletime.

(Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

A `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

1. The forName method in class Class.
2. The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
3. The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

(Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

The error message `Couldn't find or load main class XYZ`, means a lot of things:

1. You specified the wrong class (Typo)
2. The class in the classfile specified is (not) in a package. (Like `java c`, but the class is in the package a.b, so the command should be `java a.b.c`)

More information/causes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/13912132

Answer (score 1):

Both `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError` are caused when the JVM is not able to load a particular file, but their cause differs.

Java runtime throws `ClassNotFoundException` while trying to load a class at runtime only and the name was provided during runtime. In the case of `NoClassDefFoundError`, the class was present at compile-time, but Java runtime could not find it in Java classpath during runtime.

`Couldn't find or load main class` error message can be caused by various [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean), it can also be caused by `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ClassName.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClassName.class
```

Answer (score 1):

### [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

This occurs when the JVM or a `ClassLoader` tries to load a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the `new` expression) but it can not be found while it existed when the currently executing class was compiled.

### [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

As mentioned in the documentation, it is thrown when an application tries to load a class through its string name using:

1. The `forName` method in class `Class`.
2. The `findSystemClass` method in class `ClassLoader`.
3. The `loadClass` method in class `ClassLoader`.

It means that it is unknown to JVM whether the class (which is to be loaded) existed when the currently executing class was compiled.